# Google Play Console API level 26+

Tags: android, console, android-api-levels

I try to upload a beta version of an app on Google Play Console. I got this error message:

[image]

> This configuration cannot be published for the following reason(s):
>    It is forbidden that a device upgrading from API levels in range 14-25 to API levels in range 26+ should downgrade from version 118018 to version 118008, which would occur when
>      **Release track** containing any of [BETA] and
>      **Screen layouts** containing any of [small, normal, large, xlarge] and
>      **Features** containing all of [android.hardware.FAKETOUCH,   android.hardware.screen.PORTRAIT]

I'm looking for this error for a few hours, I'm out of ideas...

Edit:
Here is my build.gradle:

[Pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/quVN0HeS)

Comment: Please add your `gradle` file

Comment: API Level 26 not yet launched.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question. I've inlined the image (something you can only do after you have 5 points). I have also added the text of the error message. Next time, please do that yourself: text on images can't be searched or copied. The next question is - do the conditions in the error message hold for your APK? If so, what have you done to resolve it? Please [edit] your question accordingly. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, thanks your answers. I added my gradle file. I know API level isn't launched, this is why I don't know what to do :/

Answer (score 1):

According to [doc](https://developer.android.com/preview/migration.html) you cannot release or publish an Apk for Android O until the release.

> You cannot publish your app with this configuration. The “O” version
>   is a provisional API level that is usable only for development and
>   testing during the Android O Developer Preview. You must wait to
>   publish your Android O changes until the final API level is released,
>   and then update your configuration again at that time.

More information [here](https://medium.com/@pareshmayani/android-o-whats-new-for-androiddev-7906222e569b).